# Compositions and Partitions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

For a nonnegative integer $n$, a composition of $n$ means a partition in which the order of the parts matters. For example, the compositions of $3$ are $3$, $2+1$, $1+2$, and $1+1+1$.

Consider the generating function
$$C(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nx^n,$$
where $c_n$ is the number of distinct compositions of $n$ (note that $c_0=1$ by convention).

What is the value of $C\left(\tfrac 15\right)$?

---

My mind is blank and I don't know how to solve this problem.  Solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics) there should be section called number of compositions

Comment: You can get a closed form for $c_n$; see [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)#Number_of_compositions) of the Wikipedia article. Once you do that, you’ll find that the series is of a very familiar kind that you know how to evaluate.

Comment: I just want to know what do you mean by distinct compositions in this case?

Comment: @Drew: Exactly as compositions are defined in the Wikipedia article: an ordered sum of positive integers equal to $n$. Changing the integers or the order gives you a different composition.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note that from the link [provided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)"Compositions")
$c_n $ is simply $2^{n-1}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and from the given problem statement that $c_0 = 1$. 
Next we can continue to see that our summation will be $$C\Big(\frac{1}{5}\Big) =   c_0 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} 2^{n -1}\Big(\frac{1}{5}\Big)^{n} $$ which can be written as
$$C\Big(\frac{1}{5}\Big) = 1 + \Big(\frac{1}{5}\Big)\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} 2^{n - 1}\Big(\frac{1}{5}\Big)^{n-1}  = 1 +  \Big(\frac{1}{5}\Big)\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{2}{5}\Big)^{n-1}$$
which leads to the solution $$C\Big(\frac{1}{5}\Big) = 1 + \Big(\frac{1}{5} \Big) \Bigg(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{5}}\Bigg) = \frac{4}{3} $$

Comment: Hmm...  Something's wrong here.  $\dfrac{1}{3}$ is not the correct answer.

Comment: @Regina thanks I felt like I forgot a term.1

Comment: @Drew: You need to split off the $n=0$ term, because $c_0=1$, not $\frac12$: $$C(x)=1+\sum_{n\ge 1}2^{n-1}x^n\;,$$ and $$C\left(\frac15\right)=1+\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{2^{n-1}}{5^n}=1+\frac15\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac25\right)^n=1+\frac1{5\left(1-\frac25\right)}=1+\frac1{5-2}=\frac43\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  You are correct!