# Is there a formula for determining the number of a positive integer's factorizations (multiplicative partitions)?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

The "factorization" in the question means "multiplicative partition", so the factors can be 1 or composite numbers.

To make things simple, let $f(n, 3)$ be the number of positive integer $n$'s number of factorizations with 3 factors. (Obviously, for any $n$, $f(n, 3)\geq 1$ since we can always add some $1$'s if $n$ have less than $3$ prime factors.) For example,
\begin{array}{ccc}
24 &=& 3*2^3\\
   &=& 1*1*24 = 1*2*12=1*3*8=1*4*6\\
   &=& 2*2*6=2*3*4,
\end{array}
Thus $f(24, 3)=6$. I wonder if there is any formula for determining $f(n, 3)$ for any $n$?

The question can be divided into two parts: if the factorization contains $1$, then the number of this kind of factorizations is half of $n$'s divisors; if the factorization contains no $1$, the answer seems not that easy to find.

Comment: You are putting prime factors into indistinguishable "buckets". The complication is that your prime factors come in blocks, with items within each block being indistinguishable from one another, but items from different blocks being distinguishable. For $24$, you have three buckets (the factors in the final factorizatoin), and you have a single factor of $3$, and three factors of $2$ to distribute. Distributing the three factors of $2$ amounts to counting the number of partitions of $3$ into one, two, or three parts. Etc. This is more a combinatorics problem than a number theory one.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you so much! I just added this topic. The complicatedness here comes from the existence of the power. So is there existing result on this problem? I believe so.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, but labeling it and thinking of it as a combinatorics problem may attract people who do.

Comment: $f(n,3)$ is [A034836](https://oeis.org/A034836)

Comment: there is no known formula.

Comment: Making an answer helped me to find the same formula in other post, so marking that as potential duplicate. It has a nice proof of the same formula using Burnside's lemma.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to get a formula for solving this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916867/i-want-to-get-a-formula-for-solving-this)

Comment: To calculate this, we need the prime factorization of $n$ , for which no efficient method is known.

Comment: @Peter Suppose that its prime factorization is already known.

Comment: @SuperSaiyanGod OK, then it is quite straight forward to find and count the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to use "Composition" & "Combination" to get the Count.

Let the given number be $n=P_1^{p_1}P_2^{p_2}P_3^{p_3} \cdots P_x^{p_x}$ where the Components are Powers of Prime Numbers.

Consider $P_1^{p_1}$ : we want to split this into $k$ Parts. In other words , we want to split ${p_1}$ into $k$ "Components" , not Partitions. More-over , we want "weak Components" where we allow $0$ too.

The number of such Compositions is given by Binomial coefficients :
$$(^{p_1+k-1}C_{k-1})$$

When we choose all the other Prime Numbers , we will have to multiply the Compositions in terms of the  Binomial coefficients , to get :

$$(^{p_1+k-1}C_{k-1}) \cdot (^{p_2+k-1}C_{k-1}) \cdot (^{p_3+k-1}C_{k-1}) \cdots (^{p_x+k-1}C_{k-1})$$

In Current Case , we want $n=24=2^3 \cdot 3^1$ & $k=3$ , we can plug it in.
$$(^5C_2) \cdot (^3C_2) = 10 \cdot 3 = 30$$

Here are those 30 ways :
$$  
24====\   
=1.1.24  
=1.24.1  
=24.1.1  
=1.3.8  
=1.8.3  
=8.1.3  
=3.1.8  
=3.8.1  
=8.3.1  
=1.2.12  
=1.12.2  
=12.1.2  
=2.1.12  
=2.12.1  
=21.1.2  
=1.4.6  
=1.6.4  
=6.1.4  
=4.1.6  
=4.6.1  
=6.4.1  
=2.3.4  
=2.4.3  
=4.2.3  
=3.2.4  
=3.4.2  
=4.3.2  
=2.2.6  
=2.6.2  
=6.2.2  
$$

Taking a smaller Example :
Count the number of ways for $n=6=2^1 \cdot 3^1$ & $k=3$ :
We get $(^3C_2) \cdot (^3C_2) = 3 \cdot 3 = 9$

Here are those 9 ways :
$$  
6====\   
=1.1.6  
=1.6.1  
=6.1.1  
=1.2.3  
=1.3.2  
=3.1.2  
=2.1.3  
=2.3.1  
=3.2.1  
$$

Here are few references :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)
https://users.math.msu.edu/users/hensh/courses/482/spring19/lectures/17-IntegerPartitions1.pdf
[https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~gptesler/184a/slides/184a_ch5slides_f17-handout.pdf](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Egptesler/184a/slides/184a_ch5slides_f17-handout.pdf)
[Compositions and Partitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999800/compositions-and-partitions)